# Prevent Sidebar from appearing in some page using Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on an application, and I have a minor issue with it. I have a sidebar appearing for my login.jsx page when I don't want it to appear for that specific page, though I want it to appear on all other pages. Is there some sort of conditional I can put in it?

login.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Magic } from "magic-sdk";
import Router from "next/Router";

export default function LoginPage() {
    const {
      register, 
      handleSubmit, 
      formState: { errors },
    } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = async ({email}) => 
    {
      console.log(email);
      const magic = new Magic(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAGIC_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
      const didToken = await magic.auth.loginWithMagicLink({email})
      console.log(didToken)
      const res = await fetch("/api/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + didToken,
        }, 
        body: JSON.stringify({ email }),
      });
      if(res.status === 200) {
        // Redirect
        Router.push("/");
      } else {
        // Display an error
      }
    };

    return (
        <Container maxWidth="xs">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
              <h1>Hello and Welcome to the Enterprise Dashboard.</h1>
                <TextField 
                variant="outlined" 
                label="email" 
                fullWidth autoComplete="email" 
                autoFocus
                {...register("email", {required: "Required field", pattern: {
                  value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
                  message: "Invalid email address",
                }})}
                error={!!errors?.email}
                helperText = {errors?.email ? errors.email.message : null}
                />
              <Button type ="submit" variant= "contained" color="primary" fullWidth>
                  Login/Sign Up
              </Button>
            </form>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

And this is the part that's giving the issues. My _app.js:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
      <Sidebar>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Sidebar>
  );
}

export default MyApp
```

Here's my Sidebar.jsx component

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import {RxSketchLogo, RxDashboard, RxPerson} from 'react-icons/rx'
import {FiSettings} from 'react-icons/fi';
import {HiOutlineShoppingBag} from 'react-icons/hi';
import {BiPackage} from 'react-icons/bi';
const Sidebar = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <div className='flex'>
            <div className='fixed w-20 h-screen p-4 bg-white border-r-[1px] flex flex-col justify-between'>
                <div className='flex flex-col items-center'>
                    <Link href='/'>
                        <div className='bg-blue-800 text-white p-3 rounded-lg inline-block'>
                            <RxSketchLogo size={20} />
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                    <span className='border-b-[1px] border-gray-200 w-full p-2'>
                    <Link href='/'>
                        <div className='bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer my-4 p-3 rounded-lg inline-block'>
                                <RxDashboard size={20} />
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href='/customers'>
                        <div className='bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer my-4 p-3 rounded-lg inline-block'>
                                <RxPerson size={20} />
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href='/orders'>
                        <div className='bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer my-4 p-3 rounded-lg inline-block'>
                                <HiOutlineShoppingBag size={20} />
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href='/products'>
                        <div className='bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer my-4 p-3 rounded-lg inline-block'>
                                <BiPackage size={20} />
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href='/'>
                        <div className='bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer my-4 p-3 rounded-lg inline-block'>
                                <FiSettings size={20} />
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <main className='ml-20 w-full'>{children}</main>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Sidebar
```

I tried putting the Sidebar in different places in different files, but then unfortunately the formatting ended up being off.

Comment: Where are you storing the logged-in user data?

Comment: @yousoumar How is that relevant to the question? I just don’t want the Sidebar to appear for that login page, but for everywhere else.

Comment: Sorry. Check my answer and let me know :)

Comment: @yousoumar It won't work because my Sidebar is not configured that way. Let me edit my question to show you my Sidebar component. I mean I can try to configure it that way with the code I have, but I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: @yousoumar I just tested it. Yup! It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `Sidebar` component, you could use [`useRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter) with an `if` statement, something like this:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Sidebar({ children }) {
  const { pathname } = useRouter();

  // render the page without the sidebar
  if (pathname === "/login") {
    return children;
  }

  // render the page with the sidebar
  return <div>Sidebar {children}</div>;
}
```

In your specific case, it could be done like this:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Sidebar = ({ children }) => {
  const { pathname } = useRouter();
  return (
    <div className="flex">
      {pathname !== "/login" && (
        <div className="fixed w-20 h-screen p-4 bg-white border-r-[1px] flex flex-col justify-between">
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
            <Link href="/">
              <div className="bg-blue-800 text-white p-3 rounded-lg inline-block">
                <RxSketchLogo size={20} />
              </div>
            </Link>
            <span className="border-b-[1px] border-gray-200 w-full p-2">
              <Link href="/">
                <div className="bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer my-4 p-3 rounded-lg inline-block">
                  <RxDashboard size={20} />
                </div>
              </Link>
              <Link href="/customers">
                <div className="bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer my-4 p-3 rounded-lg inline-block">
                  <RxPerson size={20} />
                </div>
              </Link>
              <Link href="/orders">
                <div className="bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer my-4 p-3 rounded-lg inline-block">
                  <HiOutlineShoppingBag size={20} />
                </div>
              </Link>
              <Link href="/products">
                <div className="bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer my-4 p-3 rounded-lg inline-block">
                  <BiPackage size={20} />
                </div>
              </Link>
              <Link href="/">
                <div className="bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer my-4 p-3 rounded-lg inline-block">
                  <FiSettings size={20} />
                </div>
              </Link>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      <main className="ml-20 w-full">{children}</main>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much. :) This problem plagued me for a long time, and now it's finally gone.

Comment: Glad it did, and that I could help @joey :)